# getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' in rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer.get_token()

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, auth-token

i am developing web app related to election and try to implement authorize token concept using `rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers` and while running this code i encounter error related to `str` class like this:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`
from this part of code:
`data['refresh'] = str(refresh)`

```
class AuthTokenObtainSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    """
    Seializer for th user authentication object.

    Returns
    -------
        json: 'access' and 'token'
    """
    default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': _('No active account found with the given credentials')  # noqa: E501
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'] = serializers.CharField(
            style={'input_type': 'password'},
            trim_whitespace=False
        )
        self.fields['face_image'] = serializers.ImageField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """
        Validates and authenticate the user.
        """
        citizenship_number = attrs.get('citizenship_number')
        password = attrs.get('password')
        face_image = attrs.get('face_image')

        face_id = FaceIdAuthBackend()
        user = face_id.authenticate(
            citizenship_number=citizenship_number,
            password=password,
            face_id=face_image
        )

        if user is None or not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
                'no_active_account',
            )

        update_last_login(None, user)

        data = {}
        refresh = self.get_token(user)

        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)

        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        return data
```

please help me regarding this......

Comment: Why are you typecasting both refresh and refresh.access_token?

Comment: To return as json which contains access data and token data

Answer (score 1):

While i was finding solutions on different sources, i knew that this specific problem came from PyJWT package latest version so i have to downgrade it to v1.7.1 and now i am no longer getting this problem.

Source:https://github.com/jazzband/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/issues/346